# angular 2 pipe rules

Tags: angular, pipe

I write a pipe which should filter for both AUID and firstname, but somehow, it will only working for the firstname. Any one can help me figure out why?

here is the code:

```
        return value.filter((searchresult:ISearch)=>
        (filterBy2?searchresult.AU_ID.indexOf(filterBy2)!==-1:true)&&
        (filterBy?searchresult.first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy)!==-1:true)
```

Comment: Could you simplify this to a [mcve]? That seems quite convoluted, and you've provided no inputs and expected/actual outputs.

Comment: this is all the code for the pipe transform that i wrote.the question is not about the others but only the return part.Would both of them work if i wrote in this way?

Comment: ...what? *"this is all the code"* is part of the problem, have you done any debugging of your own?

Comment: yes, i did, this is the first time i use overflow, dont know how to change the question.

Comment: Then [edit] the question, per my request above.

Comment: sure, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same code provided by you. Its working for me. Can you just make sure AU_ID is a string that is being passed as a parameter not number, in that case indexOf won't work.

```
transform(value: Array<any>, filterBy: string, filterBy2: string): Array<any> {
    filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    filterBy2 = filterBy2 ? filterBy2 : null;
    return value.filter((searchresult: Array<any>) =>
      (filterBy2 ? searchresult['AU_ID'].indexOf(filterBy2) !== -1 : true) &&
      (filterBy ? searchresult['first_name'].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 : true)
    );
  }
```

In the html file, I used the below code:

```
<div *ngFor="let dummy of dummyData | screeningSearch: 'A' : '1'">hi {{dummy.first_name}}</div>
```

Kept data as below:

```
dummyData = [
    {
      'AU_ID': '1234',
      'first_name': 'Albert'
    },
    {
      'AU_ID': '5678',
      'first_name': 'Andi'
    }
  ];
```

Result:

`hi Albert`